# How to compare value in char array to another char

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I wrote a program that goes into a file and copies each line of the txt file into an index of an array, I then put that line of the txt file into another array that separates the line by characters. I'm trying to compare the first index in the character array to "H" however I am unable to. How can I compare the character inside the array to another character like "H".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    int i = 0;
    char line[256];
    char* str[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
            str[i]=strdup(line);
            strcpy(str[i],line);
            i++;
    }
    char tmp[256];
    memcpy(tmp, str[0],strlen(str[0])+1);
    if(strcmp(tmp[0],"H") == 0){
            printf("%s","is h"); 
    }else{
            printf("%s","not h");
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but `tmp` gets properly initialized to a correct value, you can can just say `tmp[0] == 'H'`. `'H'` is translated to the literal ASCII value of the character "H", so just comparing that value with the ASCII value of `tmp[0]` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do, perhaps it would be easier for you to use c++ file/array/string primitives.

Here's equivalent in c++:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream fl(argv[1]); // create file stream
    string s;
    vector<string> lines;
    while (getline(fl, s)) // while getline from input file stream succeeds
        lines.push_back(s); // add each read line to vector of strings
    string tmp = lines[0]; // first line
    if (tmp[0] == 'H') // compare first character of string `tmp`
        cout << "is h" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not h" << endl;
}
```

In your code you are passing a char to strcmp: `strcmp(tmp[0],"H")` this won't compile by c++ compiler. [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) takes two strings as inputs and compares them.

To compare individual chars: `if (tmp[0] == 'H') { ... }`.

If you wanted to compare if tmp is equal to `"H"` string: `if (0 == strcmp(tmp, "H") { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborate answer and also going in depth into why it was giving me that specific error. Changing it to if(tmp[0] == 'H') did fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the array[index] to the char. Note: chars are represented in single quotes. Double quotes are used for strings.

For example,

```
if(array[index] == 'H')
    code goes here...
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually fixed the issue that I was having in which it was unable to compare them.